# Get two tables records in a single SELECT query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I'm trying to cross-match 2 tables in a SELECT query. Also I'm filtering the results to echo only the records within 60 days. I'm using PDO to do this.

**This code works:**

```
   //$my_con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    foreach ($my_con->query("SELECT subject, date, name FROM table1") as $result){
         $gtTIme = $result['date'];
        $time = strtotime($gtTIme);
        $ftime = date("Y-m-d g:ia", $time);
        $days_ago = date('Y-m-d g:ia', strtotime('-60 days'));
        if ($ftime > $days_ago) { 
           $unl=$result['name'] . '<br />';
             echo("</option><option value=". $uml . ">". $result['name'] ."</option>");
        }
            };
```

**This code doesnot work:**

```
foreach ($my_con->query("SELECT subject, date, table1.name, score, studentname FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.name = table2.studentname ORDER BY table2.score DESC") as $result){
                $gtname = $result['name'];
                $gtsubject = $result['subject'];
                $gtScore = $result['score'];
                $gtTIme = $result['date'];

    $time = strtotime($gtTIme);
    $ftime = date("Y-m-d g:ia", $time);
    $days_ago = date('Y-m-d g:ia', strtotime('-60 days'));
    if ($ftime > $days_ago) { 
       $unl=$result['name'] . '<br />';
         echo("</option><option value=". $uml . ">". $result['name']."</option>");
    }
        };
```

**table1**

```
name  |  subject  |  date
------+-----------+----------
Kyle  |  Science  | 2014-04-03 4:00pm
John  |  Science  | 2014-05-04 9:30am
Peter |  Maths    | 2013-10-20 9:30am
```

**table2**

```
score  |  studentname
-------+-------------
78     | John
89     | Kyle
83     | Peter
```

I expect echo to be like this:

```
Kyle   Science  89
JOHN   Science  78
```

Comment: Better hope you don't have two people named "John". Wouldn't using a student ID be a better key to link these two tables? It might be worth adding a [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) because this looks mostly correct.

Comment: Describe what you mean by "does not work". In what way does it not work? Are you getting errors? If so, show them. Are you getting an unexpected result? If so, show it and explain how it differs from the expected result.

Comment: what exactly is not working? Does it produce a wrong result or do you get an error? probably its the "sort by" in your query that produces an error? if so, replace it with "order by"

Comment: you can use a primar key like student id rather than name name can be same like tadman said

Comment: thanks guys. THe difference between the WORING code and the NOT WORKING code is the JOIN statement. When I run the NOT WORKING code the loop never seem to end. I'm not receiving any errors.  Also the name fields are UNIQUE (these are username rather than actual names)

Comment: JOIN would do it, also you can filter by date/time in SQL "i.e where `date` >= '$days_ago'". Of course, use a prepared statement for that, ensure your DB and Web server are set to the same timezone (UTC ideally, same for your dates)

Comment: How long are you letting the script run when it "never seems to end"? How many records are in each table?

Comment: @PatrickQ: There are about 2500 records. I've left it for almost 15 minutes.

Comment: Considering that you're loading all of the results into memory, I'd say that you're probably hitting your memory cap and not realizing that the script is actually dying. You should check your error logs.

Comment: @PatrickQ: OK you've got a point there. I find PDO confusing. Is it possible to run another SELECT statement after the `if ($ftime > $days_ago) {` So the 'name' from **table1** can be used to bring the record from **table2**?

Comment: Do the date comparison in a `WHERE` clause instead of in your code. Something like `WHERE date > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 60 DAY`. Whether or not that works as-written depends on the format of your `date` column.